# How to remove the NameError: name 'Dataset' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I just can't find what I am doing wrong in defining df1.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Programming\Datasets\avocado.csv")

df1 = df[ df['region'] == 'Albany' ]
df1
```

NameError Traceback (most recent call last)

NameError: name 'df1' is not defined

Comment: typo `=`, need `df1 = df[ df['region'] == 'Albany' ]`

Comment: Oh Sorry! But it's still showing the same error.

Comment: I tried the exact lines you are using on my own dataset but failed to reproduce the problem. Maybe it is because of your pandas version?

Comment: What error do you get? The title contradicts the body! And can you copy-paste the code to make sure we see the exact same code that gives you the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please use double equal while filtering,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Programming\Datasets\avocado.csv")

df1 = df[df['region'] == 'Albany']
df1
```

I hope this helps,
Kind regards.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get results from code below. I wonder can you get filtered data,

```
filtered_region = df['region']=='Albany'
```

please check if filtered_region object is filled.
Than try like this

```
df1 = df[filtered_region]
df1
```

Comment: And also please try removing space at array,
df1 = df[df['region']=='Albany']
df1

Answer (score 0):

Is that your exact code? And you're running in Jupyter/Jupyterlabs, correct?

The code you pasted, with I'm assuming the Kaggle avocado.csv dataset, works for me. But I'm wondering if you are trying to call df1 before assignment. If I do either of these I get `NameError: name 'df1' is not defined`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/my_username/Downloads/avocado.csv')

df1 = df1[ df['region'] == 'Albany' ]
df1
```

or

```
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/my_username/Downloads/avocado.csv')

df1 = df[ df1['region'] == 'Albany' ]
df1
```

In both examples you can see how df1 is reference before it is assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command line and it solved my problem:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**For those using the PyTorch.**
I solved my issue by, importing the Dataset class:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
```